# How can I step into a function when its call is over multiple lines?

Tags: python, pdb

Let's say I have this code sample:

```
function1(
    'arg1',
    'arg2',
    function2(
        'arg3.1',
        'arg3.2',
    ),
)
```

According to pdb's documentation, I can step into a function by typing `s`. Pressing `s` at the first line does not have the desired effect however, it merely passes control to the subsequent line.

How can I step into `function1`, without stepping into `function2`?

Comment: Stepping immediately out of `function2` and trying to step in again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line is presented as a separate expression, pdb will step into a function right after evaluating the last expression before the closing parenthesis.

You cannot prevent stepping into `function2`; step in, straight out with `r`, then use `s` to step into `function1` when `function2` has returned. If you were to step *over* `function2` instead (when the line with `arg3.2` is presented) you'd step over both `function2` and `function1` in one go instead.